# Trying to stop RuntimeBroker.exe from using too much CPU via Batch file

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, cpu, batch-processing, windows-10

So this is the deal, my brother is using a samsung laptop and he just upgraded to Windows 10, basically everything works much better than when he was using win7, but there is this process that it seems to have a big memory/CPU leak, RuntimeBroker.exe.

I have read around and many other people seem to be reporting the same problems, I have tried many easy fixes but none seems to work. It is not an option at this time to do a clean install, and he doesn't want to go back to Win7 because of the efficiency increase, so I got to find a way to kill this process as it starts to generate problems with its CPU leak, I'm trying to use a batch file since it is by far the easiest and simplest way to do it, the problem is that the process won't stop with a batch taskkill (batch file will close or continue to loop and process remains open).

```
@echo off
:start
:killRuntime Broker
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
taskkill /im RuntimeBroker.exe >nul 2>nul || goto killRuntimeBroker
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
goto start
```

If killed via Task Manager there are no visible issues with Windows itself and this process once killed via Task Manager will re-start itself some minutes later, which is the reason why I'm using a loop.

I also changed the CPU affinity and priority of the RuntimeBroker task to the lowest possible trying to limit the leak, but it doesn't matter, RuntimeBroker  will still use an absurd amount of processing power when it starts to leak (~40% of CPU).

Help with this leak is quite appreciated, specially considering that there is a considerable amount of people having the same problem.

/**Edit** Today my brother told me that it seems to have fixed itself, very very weird, maybe a Windows update?

Comment: you should diag the CPU/memory usage with xperf/WPA: http://pastebin.com/peqLGxSa

Comment: RuntimeBroker runs code on behalf of UWA apps. If it is running out of control, take a look at what apps are running, either in the foreground or as a background task, one of the them will be causing it to go wild.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried most of the options I could find on the forums. Without success.
Finally found a fix (for now anyways) using File monitor and looking for Runtime Broker, I was able to find a lot of activity on my pictures. Went to the photo app and removed the "Source" folder in the settings it had added by default.
So far, runtime broker is no using <1% CPU and <10Mb of memory...